# how to fix a string represented form validation in django forms?

Tags: python, html, django

```
#models
class PartyTheme(models.Model):
    franchise = models.ForeignKey(Franchise, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    theme_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    theme_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.franchise.name}: {self.theme_name}: {self.theme_price}"

#forms
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['party_theme']

    def __init__(self, *args, franchise_id=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.franchise_id = franchise_id

        party_theme_choices = [(theme.id, f'{theme.theme_name} - {theme.theme_price}') for theme in PartyTheme.objects.filter(franchise_id=self.franchise_id)]
        self.fields['party_theme'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=party_theme_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), required=True)

#views
def booking_form(request, id):
    franchise_id = id
    form = BookingForm(franchise_id=franchise_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST, franchise_id=franchise_id)
        if 'paylaterbtn' in request.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.franchise_id = franchise_id
                instance.save()
    print(request.POST)

#templatetags
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def split_label_price(value):
    return value.split(' - ')

#templates
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'booking:booking_form' id=franchise_id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        {{ form.errors }}
    {% endif %}
    {% for radio in form.party_theme %}
        <input type="radio" id="{{ radio.id_for_label }}" name="party_theme" value="{{ radio.choice_label|split_label_price|first }}" {% if radio.is_checked %}checked{% endif %}>
        <label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">
            {{ radio.choice_label|split_label_price|first }}
            <span class="hidden">
                - {{ radio.choice_label|split_label_price|last }}
            </span>
        </label>
    {% endfor %}
</form>

Print Statement: "<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['somevalue'], party_theme': ['Space'], 'paylaterbtn': ['paylater']}>"

form.errors: "party_theme: Select a valid choice. Space is not one of the available choices."
```

I've tried changing the model string representation to match the template form value="{{ radio.choice_label }}" but it gives out the same error! What's a viable way to fix this? I wanna be able to save the form field "party_theme", is there a better way to go about this? I'm handling this form field manually because of how it's styled.

Comment: Kindly share error, and your expected response in html

Comment: @VinitaSonakiya "form.errors" is the error, since I'm manually handling the "party_theme" form field, I'm not able to save it properly! The expected response would be to not get this error and submit this field data properly haha

Comment: Share enough information to reproduce the error. E.g. `Booking` model is missing...